# Meaning of ETag in firebase response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Could you please explain what does it mean ETag header in firebase response on firebase function's call? 
Rephrasing question. 
In my case I don't need ETag, and I want to change the behaviour.
How can I implement this?

For example, I have simple function on the cloud side that return json:

```
const getObject = functions.https.onCall((data, context)=>({x:1, y:2}));
```

In browser I see ETag presented in http response, as you can see I don't get any data from cloud store in my handler. 
Next question, call (for example, in angularfire) to callable functions translates to http POST request, what is the best way to modify response in onCall handler to force caching abitrary json data on the client and reverse proxy side?

Answer (score 0):

The [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) header has the following purpose:

> The ETag HTTP response header is an identifier for a specific version of a resource. It allows caches to be more efficient, and saves bandwidth, as a web server does not need to send a full response if the content has not changed. On the other side, if the content has changed, etags are useful to help prevent simultaneous updates of a resource from overwriting each other ("mid-air collisions").

Comment: in common sense I understand this, but question was in the context of firebase, why firebase generate ETag in the case. For my case it increases traffic I don't want this header or give me the way to control this behaviour

Comment: @Oleg this is not Firebase, this is plain HTTP protocol, while "an identifier for a specific version of a resource" certainly applies. eg. just imagine two clients manipulating the same resource, which is exactly what is meant with "mid-air collision". when caching, the cache needs to adhere to ETag identifiers (web-browsers may handle this transparently, so it depends what kind of client it is).

Comment: as you can see `const getObject = functions.https.onCall((data, context)=>({x:1, y:2}));` simple function on the firebase site (web server). All stuff related to http is performed at the firebase. After function returns object firebase makes response, convert it to http response. That does mean that firebase team control what data code to headers and other http stuff. I try to tell you second time that ETag header is a creativity of firebase team they decide to use Etag to adhere some practices.

Comment: @Oleg ETag is not Firebase specific at all - despite the fact that it is an ideal use-case for that header... the description of what is good for exactly matches the given scenario, eg. with multiple WebSocket clients. with one single client, it only affects the caching, because mid-air collisions are not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You use the ETag for conditional updates. Typically when you don't want to overwrite another user's changes to a document.

Another use case is when you're making a partial update to a document and the change  assumes that the rest of the document has not changed in the meantime; there are invariants to protect.

Don't confuse this with the concurrency model for transactions. Server-side SDKs just keep retrying on failures caused by write contention. This just brute forces your changes in.

This is more for when a user has been editing a customer's order for 10 minutes, then saves it, but some other user, like a customer services person, has already made changes, so you can't overwrite them else their changes will be lost.

So you need to inform the user that someone else has changed stuff and they need to reload and potentially lose their edits.